# Multisite with path, how to change the main site

Tags: multisite, wp-config

I have a network installed on my wordpress with 4 websites

- domain.com --> Old website
- domain.com/fr --> New website in French
- domain.com/en --> new website in english
- domain.com/es --> New website in spanish

Instead of copy/pasting the contents of the new FR website onto the old website, i'd rather change the "main site" of my network and show everyone that goes to domain.com the new FR website.

2 options:

- Either I redirect everyone to domain.com/fr. I've searched for ways to do that but I did not manage to implement any of the solutions. Some speak of creating a php file, uploading the plugin on the FTP, activating it and voila... but no luck.
- I change the main site in the wp-config file and the old website on my domain becomes domain.com/oldFR and the new FR website becomes domain.com.

  ```
  define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain.com');
  define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
  define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
  define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
  ```

This second option seems a lot better to me. But i can't get it to work. I'm not sure what to change in the wp-config file nor am i sure if that is the only thing to do or if anything is required.

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Ok I actually ended up finding an answer by myself :D

Check out this blog post: http://halfelf.org/2014/switching-main-blog-multisite/